How to determine correct correlation structure for GEE model?
I want to use Generalized Estimating Equations (GEE) to model longitudinal survey data. Participants' responses were recorded at two separate treatment sites at three timepoints, but the exact days between each time point varied slightly across the participants. From what I can see so far, it looks like a first-order autoregressive structure would be best suited for my data, and I can specify the spacing between responses using geepack.
I have also seen information on exchangeable correlation structures. However, my understanding is that this structure assumes that the correlation between timepoint 1 and timepoint 2 is the same as the correlation between timepoint 1 and timepoint 3 for all participants, which would not work for my dataset.
I am hoping to get a bit more insight into how to decide what correlation structure is most appropriate.
